# Automatically claim transferred money PayPal

Tags: paypal, paypal-adaptive-payments

I'm making an application that uses `Adaptive Payments`.

I make a `preapproved payment` and after that a `parallel payment` to two accounts.

In both accounts I have to claim the money as shown here:
[image: Payment to account 1]

[image]

In both account I have to manually accept every single payment, which is quite user unfriendly. Is there a way to send the money in a `parallel payment` so that the user doesn't have to click `Accept` on the payment? The account are opened in USD, but I'm sending EUR is that the problem ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Well if you want the money to be claimed automatically, the receiver should hold the same currency as the sender is sending the amount. Otherwise, it will fall into unclaimed status and the receiver has to manually accept them.

Comment: That was it, just tried it with USD and no confirmation was necessary. Thank you :)